# I just started with C#, following the freeCodeCamp.org tutorial, and I was wondering why this code doesn't work

Tags: c#

[my issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5sbh.png)

I can not use the 'play' button nor CTRL+f5.
Why does it not let me play the code and open a console.

I tried to open a console with the words "Hello World", but it doesn't let me open up a console, at least I think.

Comment: Please include more error details. What happens when you try to use the play button?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine, I am unable to use the play button, as you can see it's gray in the top. I'm new so I might be mistaken but that's my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has no projects. You've got a source file, but it's not in your solution.

Right-click on "Solution 'giraffe'" (in the top-right of your window) , choose "Add new project", then follow prompts to create a new Console Application. That new project will then show in the Solution Explorer (the right-hand panel), and you'll be able to run it.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it works thanks to you, sorry for my clumsiness lol.

Comment: @jouri if answer works for you - please do not forget to mark it as accepted one (checkmark on the left)

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks, as you notice I'm new to this platform aswell as C# hahah.